# Cannot read style properties of null (even though the line of code is inside of an "if" asking is the variable is defined

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, null, typeof

In my website, there is a particular tab that only loades for specific users.

`<?php  if($User["UID"] == $SpaceCreatorUID){ echo "";?> <button class="button-container" id="qr-button">Mi QR<div id="qr-indicator" class="indicator"></div> </button> <?php echo ""; } ?>`

Nothing special; works perfectly. However, when the tab does not load for a user (which is perfect), my JS code stops working at the following line (83):

`qrIndicator.style.display = "none";`

Makes total sense, since I would be trying to define the style property for a null object. Thus, I made the following change (line 83):

`if (typeof qrIndicator !== 'undefined'){qrIndicator.style.display = "none";};`

However, it keeps throwing the same error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'). What is it that I'm missing or not understanding?

I'm leaving the following line (14) for context:

`try{var qrIndicator = document.getElementById("qr-indicator");}finally{};`

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Your check passes beacause `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: How can I fix that? (I'm a newbie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no need for a `try/catch`, that won’t throw, it’ll instead return `null` which is easy to test for.

```js
var qrIndicator = document.getElementById("qr-indicator");

if (qrIndicator){
  qrIndicator.style.display = "none";
}
```